# What's the requirement to DIY PD aware USB connector?

Tags: usb

According to [some research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_Power_Delivery), I should be able to pull +12v from a USB power source assuming my device is some how telling the power source that it is ready to receive +12v?

I've seen a YouTube clip (can't find it conveniently enough tho) of a kid putting a resistor across two wires on a stripped USB cable to achieve something along these lines.

So my question is, how do you instruct the power source to send +12v (1.5A is fine) or is this even possible?

Comment: I am sure the usb 3.1 specification linked on that page tells you. However nobody knows if anyone correctly implements that...

Comment: It states that USB 2 will deliver 1.5A across 12V as well, I'm extremely interested in knowing how I can utilize my 1.5A phonecharger to deliver me this +12 V of glory!

Comment: If your phone charger doesn't support it, which is very unlikely, you can't. In fact a bit of googling and I can't find anyone advertising USB-PD chargers at all!

Comment: Assuming both charger and device are compatible with new USB type C, I think, it is not just the connector (USB type C), both the charger and the device has to communicate each other first. Once deal is done, 12 V can be pulled out.

Comment: Looking at the specifications you need PD capable plugs and cables and a resistor from the new ID pin to ground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As PlasmaHH says, the needed info is indeed in the USB3.1 specifications.
A quick scan of USB_PD_R2_0 V1.1 - 20150507.pdf seems to indicate that getting 12Volts requires an intelligent charger.  The specifications call for only allowing 12V after negotiation over the data bus.

To get that PDF, you have to down load a 54MB zip file from [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/)   Once you unpack it, you get a big pile of PDFs, including USB_PD_R2_0 V1.1

Section 3.4 describes the various ways the cable can identify itself, and section 6.4.2 mentions the messages needed to request 12V.

Comment: THank you, this was you going out of your way to do something you shouldn't need to do. And that is find the documentation and skim through it on my behalf. For this I thank you and reward you with a mark of solution. Also the information is great, i'll build some sort of 5v driven 12v negotiator on the data bus! Cheers!